Finding functions $f$, $g$, $h$ such that $f(g(h))(x) = \frac{4}{5+x^2}$. Are multiple answers possible?

Given, $$T(x)= f(g(h))(x) = \frac{4}{5+x^2}$$
Find $f$, $g$, $h$

My solution:
$$f= \frac{4}{5+x}, \qquad g= x^2, \quad h= x$$
Answer key has a different solution. Many textbooks tell ahead if there are more than one correct answers. This particular book by Sheldon Axler does not say that.

There are always more than one solution. If $(f,g,h)$ is a solution, then you can take $u(x)=x^3$, $v(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$ and consider $(f\circ u, v\circ g\circ u, v\circ h)$. Same thing can be done with $u$ being any other bijection.

It’s sort of “cheating” to compose with the identity. Multiple answers though, are of course possible (even with this restriction).

Certainly, your solution works; presumably, the book's does, too. So, you already have an answer to your question about whether multiple answers are possible. (Another: $f(x)=T(x)$, $g(x)=x$, $h(x)=x$, but as @Malady mentions, it seems like cheating to use the identity function.) You might consider providing the book's solution here to compare and contrast the relative merits. (Plus, it'll help people here avoid duplicating that solution when discussing examples.) Of course, whether one solution is "better" than another would ultimately be a matter of opinion and/or context.

I guess, I should take care NOT to use identity this way. Actually, before you mentioned it I did not actually notice that I DID use an identity.

Book's Solution: $f= \frac{4}{X}$, $g= 5+X$, $h= X^2$

Another solution. Take $f(x) = 4x$, $g(x) = \frac{1}{5 + x}$, $h(x) = x^{2}$
$$f(g(h(x))) = \frac{4}{5+x^{2}}.$$
